# Is this set a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to prove that the following set is a closed set.

$A$={$n$+$\frac{1}{2n}$:$n\in\mathbb{N}$}

I learned that if a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ contains the limits of all convergent sequences in $E$, then it is closed. And the set $E$ is open if $\mathbb{R}\backslash$$E$ is closed.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Hint: $n < n+1/(2n) < n+1$

Comment: @Crostul No: e.g., the set of numbers $1/n$ is dicrete but is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

For two points $x \neq y$ from $A$, we always have $d(x,y) \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

This means that the only convergent sequences are the ones that are eventually constant (take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ in the definition of convergence), and any set is closed under limits of eventually constant sequences, so $A$ is closed under limits of convergent sequences, so $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The complement of $A$ in $\mathbb R$ is

$$A^c =\left(-\infty, \frac{3}{2}\right) \cup \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \left( n+ \frac{1}{2n}, n+1+\frac{1}{2n+2}\right). $$